# Адаптация слайдера под моб версию ( сделать два блока один под другим )

Tags: css

Всем привет, возник вопрос , нужно выполнить адаптивность слайдера. На пк он как на примере https://prnt.sc/sncbrx
На моб правый блок ( blackbox) должен падать под основную часть изображения , пример https://prnt.sc/sncchh
Сам слайдер реализован вот так

```html
  <style>
    /* стили для элемента body */
   

    /* стили основного контейнера слайдера */
    .slider {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    max-width: 1334px;
    margin-top: -75px;
    }

    /* стили для обёртки, в которой заключены слайды */
    .slider__wrapper {
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    /* стили для контейнера слайдов */
    .slider__items {
      display: flex;
      transition: transform 0.6s ease;
    }

    /* стили для слайдов */
    .slider__item {
      flex: 0 0 100%;
      max-width: 100%;
    }

    /* стили для кнопок "вперед" и "назад" */
    .slider__control {
          position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    display: none;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 40px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    height: 50px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    background: rgb(243, 156, 18);
    }

    .slider__control_show {
      display: flex;
    }

    .slider__control:hover,
    .slider__control:focus {
      color: #fff;
      text-decoration: none;
      outline: 0;
      opacity: 0.9;
    }

    .slider__control_prev {
      left: 0;
    }

    .slider__control_next {
      right: 0;
    }

    .slider__control::before {
      content: '';
      display: inline-block;
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
      background: transparent no-repeat center center;
      background-size: 100% 100%;
    }

    .slider__control_prev::before {
      background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='%23fff' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3E%3Cpath d='M5.25 0l-4 4 4 4 1.5-1.5-2.5-2.5 2.5-2.5-1.5-1.5z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
    }

    .slider__control_next::before {
      background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='%23fff' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3E%3Cpath d='M2.75 0l-1.5 1.5 2.5 2.5-2.5 2.5 1.5 1.5 4-4-4-4z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
    }

    /* стили для индикаторов */
    .slider__indicators {
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 10px;
      left: 0;
      z-index: 15;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      padding-left: 0;
      margin-right: 15%;
      margin-left: 15%;
      list-style: none;
      margin-top: 0;
      margin-bottom: 0;
    }

    .slider__indicators li {
      box-sizing: content-box;
      flex: 0 1 auto;
      width: 5px;
      height: 4px;
      margin-right: 3px;
      margin-left: 3px;
      text-indent: -999px;
      cursor: pointer;
      background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
      background-clip: padding-box;
      border-top: 10px solid transparent;
      border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
    }

    .slider__indicators li.active {
      background-color: #fff;
    }

    /* для стилизации текущего слайдера */
    .img-fluid {
      display: inline-block;
      height: auto;
      max-width: 100%;
    }
.blackbox{
    background: #0000009e;
    width: 510px;
    height: 560px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 500;
    margin-left: 62%;
}
.headslide {
    margin-top: 180px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    font-size: 34px;
    color: #F39C12;
    text-align: left;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.textslide {
    max-width: 410px;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    line-height: 1.5;
}
.buttonslide {
    width: 180px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #F39C12;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    position: absolute;
}
.buttonslide:hover{
  background:#F39C12;
  opacity: 0.9;
}
.buttonslide span {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    padding-top: 15px;
    margin-left: -40px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
  </style>




<div class="slider">
    <div class="slider__wrapper">
      <div class="slider__items">
        <div class="slider__item">
          <div class="blackbox">
            <div class="headslide">Заголовок</div>
            <div class="textslide"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At. </div>
            <div class="buttonslide"><a href="#"><span>Подробнее</span></a></div>
          </div>
          <div style="height: 560px;"><img src="/image/sliderpng.png" width="1336px" height="560px"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="slider__item">
          <div class="blackbox">
            <div class="headslide">Заголовок 3</div>
            <div class="textslide"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At. </div>
            <div class="buttonslide"><a href="#"><span>Подробнее</span></a></div>
          </div>
          <div style="height: 560px;"><img src="/image/sliderpng.png" width="1336px" height="560px"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="slider__item">
          <div class="blackbox">
            <div class="headslide">Заголовок 2</div>
            <div class="textslide"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At. </div>
            <div class="buttonslide"><a href="#"><span>Подробнее</span></a></div>
          </div>
          <div style="height: 560px;"><img src="/image/sliderpng.png" width="1336px" height="560px"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> 
    <a class="slider__control slider__control_prev slider__control_show" href="#" role="button"></a>
    <a class="slider__control slider__control_next slider__control_show" href="#" role="button"></a>
</div>

  <script>
    'use strict';
    var slideShow = (function () {
      return function (selector, config) {
        var
          _slider = document.querySelector(selector), // основный элемент блока
          _sliderContainer = _slider.querySelector('.slider__items'), // контейнер для .slider-item
          _sliderItems = _slider.querySelectorAll('.slider__item'), // коллекция .slider-item
          _sliderControls = _slider.querySelectorAll('.slider__control'), // элементы управления
          _currentPosition = 0, // позиция левого активного элемента
          _transformValue = 0, // значение транфсофрмации .slider_wrapper
          _transformStep = 100, // величина шага (для трансформации)
          _itemsArray = [], // массив элементов
          _timerId,
          _indicatorItems,
          _indicatorIndex = 0,
          _indicatorIndexMax = _sliderItems.length - 1,
          _stepTouch = 50,
          _config = {
            isAutoplay: false, // автоматическая смена слайдов
            directionAutoplay: 'prev', // направление смены слайдов
            delayAutoplay: 3500, // интервал между автоматической сменой слайдов
            isPauseOnHover: true // устанавливать ли паузу при поднесении курсора к слайдеру
          };

        // настройка конфигурации слайдера в зависимости от полученных ключей
        for (var key in config) {
          if (key in _config) {
            _config[key] = config[key];
          }
        }

        // наполнение массива _itemsArray
        for (var i = 0, length = _sliderItems.length; i < length; i++) {
          _itemsArray.push({ item: _sliderItems[i], position: i, transform: 0 });
        }

        // переменная position содержит методы с помощью которой можно получить минимальный и максимальный индекс элемента, а также соответствующему этому индексу позицию
        var position = {
          getItemIndex: function (mode) {
            var index = 0;
            for (var i = 0, length = _itemsArray.length; i < length; i++) {
              if ((_itemsArray[i].position < _itemsArray[index].position && mode === 'min') || (_itemsArray[i].position > _itemsArray[index].position && mode === 'max')) {
                index = i;
              }
            }
            return index;
          },
          getItemPosition: function (mode) {
            return _itemsArray[position.getItemIndex(mode)].position;
          }
        };

        // функция, выполняющая смену слайда в указанном направлении
        var _move = function (direction) {
          var nextItem, currentIndicator = _indicatorIndex;;
          if (direction === 'next') {
            _currentPosition++;
            if (_currentPosition > position.getItemPosition('max')) {
              nextItem = position.getItemIndex('min');
              _itemsArray[nextItem].position = position.getItemPosition('max') + 1;
              _itemsArray[nextItem].transform += _itemsArray.length * 100;
              _itemsArray[nextItem].item.style.transform = 'translateX(' + _itemsArray[nextItem].transform + '%)';
            }
            _transformValue -= _transformStep;
            _indicatorIndex = _indicatorIndex + 1;
            if (_indicatorIndex > _indicatorIndexMax) {
              _indicatorIndex = 0;
            }
          } else {
            _currentPosition--;
            if (_currentPosition < position.getItemPosition('min')) {
              nextItem = position.getItemIndex('max');
              _itemsArray[nextItem].position = position.getItemPosition('min') - 1;
              _itemsArray[nextItem].transform -= _itemsArray.length * 100;
              _itemsArray[nextItem].item.style.transform = 'translateX(' + _itemsArray[nextItem].transform + '%)';
            }
            _transformValue += _transformStep;
            _indicatorIndex = _indicatorIndex - 1;
            if (_indicatorIndex < 0) {
              _indicatorIndex = _indicatorIndexMax;
            }
          }
          _sliderContainer.style.transform = 'translateX(' + _transformValue + '%)';
          _indicatorItems[currentIndicator].classList.remove('active');
          _indicatorItems[_indicatorIndex].classList.add('active');
        };

        // функция, осуществляющая переход к слайду по его порядковому номеру
        var _moveTo = function (index) {
          var i = 0, direction = (index > _indicatorIndex) ? 'next' : 'prev';
          while (index !== _indicatorIndex && i <= _indicatorIndexMax) {
            _move(direction);
            i++;
          }
        };

        // функция для запуска автоматической смены слайдов через промежутки времени
        var _startAutoplay = function () {
          if (!_config.isAutoplay) {
            return;
          }
          _stopAutoplay();
          _timerId = setInterval(function () {
            _move(_config.directionAutoplay);
          }, _config.delayAutoplay);
        };

        // функция, отключающая автоматическую смену слайдов
        var _stopAutoplay = function () {
          clearInterval(_timerId);
        };

        // функция, добавляющая индикаторы к слайдеру
        var _addIndicators = function () {
          var indicatorsContainer = document.createElement('ol');
          indicatorsContainer.classList.add('slider__indicators');
          for (var i = 0, length = _sliderItems.length; i < length; i++) {
            var sliderIndicatorsItem = document.createElement('li');
            if (i === 0) {
              sliderIndicatorsItem.classList.add('active');
            }
            sliderIndicatorsItem.setAttribute("data-slide-to", i);
            indicatorsContainer.appendChild(sliderIndicatorsItem);
          }
          _slider.appendChild(indicatorsContainer);
          _indicatorItems = _slider.querySelectorAll('.slider__indicators > li')
        };

        var _isTouchDevice = function () {
          return !!('ontouchstart' in window || navigator.maxTouchPoints);
        };

        // функция, осуществляющая установку обработчиков для событий 
        var _setUpListeners = function () {
          var _startX = 0;
          if (_isTouchDevice()) {
            _slider.addEventListener('touchstart', function (e) {
              _startX = e.changedTouches[0].clientX;
              _startAutoplay();
            });
            _slider.addEventListener('touchend', function (e) {
              var
                _endX = e.changedTouches[0].clientX,
                _deltaX = _endX - _startX;
              if (_deltaX > _stepTouch) {
                _move('prev');
              } else if (_deltaX < -_stepTouch) {
                _move('next');
              }
              _startAutoplay();
            });
          } else {
            for (var i = 0, length = _sliderControls.length; i < length; i++) {
              _sliderControls[i].classList.add('slider__control_show');
            }
          }
          _slider.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            if (e.target.classList.contains('slider__control')) {
              e.preventDefault();
              _move(e.target.classList.contains('slider__control_next') ? 'next' : 'prev');
              _startAutoplay();
            } else if (e.target.getAttribute('data-slide-to')) {
              e.preventDefault();
              _moveTo(parseInt(e.target.getAttribute('data-slide-to')));
              _startAutoplay();
            }
          });
          document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function () {
            if (document.visibilityState === "hidden") {
              _stopAutoplay();
            } else {
              _startAutoplay();
            }
          }, false);
          if (_config.isPauseOnHover && _config.isAutoplay) {
            _slider.addEventListener('mouseenter', function () {
              _stopAutoplay();
            });
            _slider.addEventListener('mouseleave', function () {
              _startAutoplay();
            });
          }
        };

        // добавляем индикаторы к слайдеру
        _addIndicators();
        // установливаем обработчики для событий
        _setUpListeners();
        // запускаем автоматическую смену слайдов, если установлен соответствующий ключ
        _startAutoplay();

        return {
          // метод слайдера для перехода к следующему слайду
          next: function () {
            _move('next');
          },
          // метод слайдера для перехода к предыдущему слайду          
          left: function () {
            _move('prev');
          },
          // метод отключающий автоматическую смену слайдов
          stop: function () {
            _config.isAutoplay = false;
            _stopAutoplay();
          },
          // метод запускающий автоматическую смену слайдов
          cycle: function () {
            _config.isAutoplay = true;
            _startAutoplay();
          }
        }
      }
    }());

    slideShow('.slider', {
      isAutoplay: true
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: может быть пересмотреть чуть чуть вёрстку ? сделать flexbox и в нужном медиа запросе сделать flex-direction: column

Comment: не очень знаюсь на flex.. так как верстать только начинаю 
если сможете с этого привести наглядный  пример кодом , буду признателен

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/abvxBJP - примерно так но это не флексбокс

Comment: еще возник вопрос , в первую прокрутку почему то  blackbox грузится только на 1 слайде и без opacity
а на остальных 2 слайдах просто картинка 
и только со второго прокрута нормальное отображение 
что может быть?